# Vuetify, closing Snackbar without closing dialog

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to combine the use of a dialog and a snackbar with VueJS. The problem is the following:

**Expected Behaviour:**

*I should be able to close the snackbar without closing the dialog*

**What happens now:**

*The dialog is being closed when the snackbar is clicked*

---

Here is a JSFiddle to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/q6m2j4ae/5/

Here is the markup for the problem:

```
<v-container>
    <v-dialog v-model="displayDialog" max-width="300px">
        <v-card flat>
            This is the dialog content
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <v-snackbar
            v-model="displaySnackbar"
            :top="true"
            :right="true"
            :vertical="true"
            color="success"
    >
        Some Content
        <v-btn flat @click.stop="displaySnackbar = false">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
</v-container>
```

As you can see, the `v-snackbar` is at the same level of the dialog. I am not allowed to nest the snackbar into the dialog. But even if I try the snackbar is not even displayed.

**What I tried:**

- I thought that the `stop` modifier on the click event `@click.stop="displaySnackbar = false"` would be enough to not close the dialog.
- I checked the `z-index` applied to the elements. The snackbar has a `z-index: 1000` and the dialog has a `z-index:200`. So I'm not able to adjust that value.

**Is it a bug? How could I solve the problem on my hand?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A workaround (if the "dismiss on clicking outside the dialog" function is not needed) is to add the property `persistent` to the dialog.

The click outside the dialog (when clicking the close in the snackbar) is the reason your dialog gets dismissed

Comment: Yes, that does the trick but I would have loved being able to dismiss the dialog anyway if user clicked somewhere on the screen.. But it solves the main problem, thank you :)

Comment: is rare but in my case,my dialog is on full screen and this close when have `persistent` attribute, my solution is remove full screen attribute and keep `persistent`...

Comment: The downside with this is you don't get the close-on-esc behavior that dialogs without `persistent` enjoy. :(

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for a good solution: add `<div class="v-menu__content--active" style="display:none; z-index:1000;"></div>` as a child of your `v-snackbar`. This tricks `v-dialog` to think it was not the active component when click outside happened and prevents closing.

Comment: Putting that div inside of my `v-snackbar` causes the snackbar to not appear at all. It's supposed to go between the `<v-snackbar>` and `</v-snackbar>` tags, right?

Comment: I suppose that was a stupid question. Your solution just seemed pretty straightforward and when it didn't work I just wanted to check to make sure I wasn't being an absolute idiot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have produced a solution :

https://codepen.io/alignnc/pen/OdWvJd

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-layout row justify-center>
                <v-btn
                    color="primary"
                    dark 
                    @click.native.stop="dialog = true">
                    Open Dialog
                </v-btn>
                <!-- dialog -->
                <v-dialog 
                    v-model="dialog" 
                    max-width="290" 
                    :transition="false"
                    :persistent="snack">               
                    <v-card>          
                        <v-card-text>
                            Click "agree" to set <br>
                            this.dialog to false,<br>
                            and this.snack to true
                        </v-card-text>
                        <v-btn
                            @click.prevent ="snack = true">
                            Agree
                        </v-btn>          
                    </v-card>        
                </v-dialog>      
                <v-snackbar
                    v-model='snack'
                    color='error'
                    :top='true'>
                    Hello
                    <v-btn
                        color="accent"
                        flat
                        @click="snack = false">
                        Close
                    </v-btn>
                </v-snackbar>
            </v-layout>
        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          dialog: false,
          snack: false
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```